# How to write the signature of a method in LaTex?

Tags: latex

I'm writing an article in LaTex about programming and I need to write the signature of a C++ method using a specific format, only the statement of the method, not the body.

for example:

```
void cvtColor( InputArray src, OutputArray dst, int code, int dstCn=0 );
```

I would like something like this:

```
void cvtColor( InputArray src, 
               OutputArray dst, 
               int code, 
               int dstCn=0 
              );
```

Thanks.

Comment: If this is about how to code this in latex, take a look at [tex.se]. You'll have more luck there than here, probably.

Comment: Maybe you would find package [verbatim](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/verbatim) useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use:

```latex
\medskip
\lstinputlisting[caption={}, label=lst:labeltest, style=input]{code.cpp}
```

you can easly modify your code inside `code.cpp` in the view how you want.

Comment: @jperezmartin can you up-vote me? :-) also as final answer! I think you solved it.